# Haskell Map Function for Algebraic Data types

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, higher-order-functions, fold, algebraic-data-types

I have an algebraic data type Newb defined like below. Now I want to write a custom map function for it without using recursion.Further I have a foldNewb function which could also help.

```
 data Newb a = Leaf a | Node [Newb a]


foldNewb:: (a->b)->([b]->b)->Newb a -> b
foldNewb f _ (Leaf a) = f a
foldNewb f1 f2 (Node a) = f2 (map (foldNewb f1 f2) a)


Newbmap :: (a->b)-> Newb a -> Newb b

Newbmap f (Leaf a) = (Leaf (f a))
Newbmap f (Node a) = (Node (foldNewb f concat a))
```

above is my attempt at implementing this function. I can't get any further than this and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr** Here's your function. But I recommend reading on to see how I came up with this, so you can work out the thought process.

```
newbmap :: (a->b)-> Newb a -> Newb b
newbmap f = foldNewb (Leaf . f) Node
```

You're pretty close, and you're using `foldNewb` correctly, but you're overthinking it.

First, you can't name a function `Newbmap`. Capital names are reserved for types. So we'll call it `newbmap`. Now, `foldNewb` already handles both of the cases `Leaf` and `Node`, so we shouldn't have to pattern match in `newbmap` at all. In fact, your first `newbmap` case does exactly what `foldNewb` would do anyway, so let's just consider the second case.

```
newbmap :: (a->b)-> Newb a -> Newb b
newbmap f (Node a) = (Node (foldNewb f concat a))
```

We want to fold over our data structure. In particular, we want our fold call to completely produce the new data structure. We *shouldn't* need to explicitly use `Node` at the end, since, again, `foldNewb` already does that work for us.

```
newbmap :: (a->b)-> Newb a -> Newb b
newbmap f a = foldNewb f concat a
```

Now in the first case, we need a function `a -> Newb b` (since the result is going to be of type `Newb b`). You've passed `f :: a -> b`, which is very close to what you want. We simply need to compose it with a function `b -> Newb b`, and `Leaf` will do exactly that.

```
newbmap :: (a->b)-> Newb a -> Newb b
newbmap f a = foldNewb (Leaf . f) concat a
```

For the second argument, you want `[Newb b] -> Newb b`, which again is very easily done by `Node`.

```
newbmap :: (a->b)-> Newb a -> Newb b
newbmap f a = foldNewb (Leaf . f) Node a
```

And (although it doesn't make a difference), we can pointfree the final argument.

```
newbmap :: (a->b)-> Newb a -> Newb b
newbmap f = foldNewb (Leaf . f) Node
```

So there's a working `newbmap` function. Now, as for how I came up with all of those types, if you're using GHC, there's a very helpful feature called *type holes* that you can use to identify what sort of types you need. So (and I did exactly this when debugging your function) if you write

```
newbmap :: (a->b)-> Newb a -> Newb b
newbmap f = foldNewb _1 _2
```

then you'll get very specific GHC messages telling you `_1 :: a -> Newb b` and `_2 :: [Newb b] -> Newb b`. Then your challenge is simply to find functions with those particular types. And this is where I came up with `Leaf . f` and `Node`.

Answer (score 1):

Without using `foldNewb`:

```
data Newb a = Leaf a | Node [ Newb a]
  deriving (Show)

newbMap :: (a -> b) -> Newb a -> Newb b
newbMap f (Leaf a) = Leaf (f a)
-- since a :: [Newb a] in the below clause, we can map (newbMap f) over the elements 
newbMap f (Node a) = Node (map (newbMap f) a)

tree = Node [ Leaf 1, Node [Leaf 2, Leaf 3], Leaf 4]
mapped = newbMap (+1) tree -- Node [Leaf 2,Node [Leaf 3,Leaf 4],Leaf 5]
```